# VSCode shortcut to focus and navigate file in source control view

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

In VS Code, when the source control view is focused, I want to focus the first file in "staged Changes", navigate and focus between them, is there a keyboard shortcut to do this?

I want the behavior works like "Search: Focus Next Search Result，Search: Focus Previous Search Result". but in source view stage section

Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about:
[image: screenshot of source control view with an arrow pointing to first entry]

Comment: related? https://stackoverflow.com/q/77055472/147511

Comment: related, but not the same question I think: [How can I cycle through all source control changes in a VS Code workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76481818/11107541)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this directly from anywhere in the scm view, but you will need a macro extension like [Multi-Command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command).  And this keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "alt+u",            // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": {
    "sequence": [
      "list.focusFirst",     // focuses the commit message input, as close as you can get
      "list.focusDown",
      "list.focusDown",
      "list.focusDown",
      "list.select"     // add this to also open the scm diff
    ],
  },
  "when": "focusedView == workbench.scm"
}
```

When you are focused in the scm view you could go down/up a file and focus it with this keybinding:

```
  {
    "key": "alt+down", // whatever keybinding you want
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": {
      "sequence": [
        "list.focusDown",    // or "list.focusUp"
        "list.select"
      ],
    },
    "when": "focusedView == workbench.scm"
  }
```

To open the next item in the scm view and return focus to that scm view, try this keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "alt+down", // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": {
    "interval": 400,     // need a delay
    "sequence": [
      "list.focusDown",
      "list.select",
      "workbench.action.focusSideBar",
    ],
  },
  "when": "focusedView == workbench.scm"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works,but If I want to navigate between these files and focus,  work like  "search.action.focusNextSearchResult"  how to make this multicommand?

Comment: Can you explain a little more the sequence of what you want to do - I don't quite follow.

Comment: I edited the answer if what you want to do is focus the first file and focus that file in an editor.

Comment: (up){
      "sequence": [
        "workbench.scm.focus",
        "list.focusUp", 
        "list.select"
      ]
  },
  (down){
      "sequence": [
        "workbench.scm.focus",
        "list.focusDown",  
        "list.select"
      ]
  },
  (focus first){
      "sequence": [
        "workbench.scm.focus",
        "list.focusFirst",   
        "list.focusDown",
        "list.focusDown",
        "list.focusDown",
        "list.select"
      ]
  }

Comment: thank you,

now I'm using three shortcut(up,down, focusfirst) to control this 

If the selected list is above the first change file,   I want the shortcut（up or down） to focus the first change file directly. so I hope I can navigate only use two shortcut(up and down), Is there a way to do that? (i think it relate to the “when” condition ,When the focused item is above the first)

Comment: So you want only two shortcuts: focusFirst and down?  You do not care about focusUp one at a time?

Comment: Now in the workflow, there are three shortcut("up", "down", "focusfirst" ), I should press the "focusfirst", then use "up" or "down"  to navigate between changed files.  . I want only use two shortcut "up" and "down" : if use "up" or "down", and  the focused List is above the first changed file, (e.g. in Message Section or Commit Section in SCM), it should focus the first file in changes,   so I want to use "when-caluse" to do this, but don't know how to write the condition "when focused list is above first changed file", If I can write this condition, I can use the multicommand do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy and fast with regular keyboard navigation.

You can switch to the source control pane with the `View: Show Source Control` command, or the corresponding <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> shortcut. Or if it's already the current tab of the sidebar and the sidebar is not focused, focus it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>. See also [How can I navigate and manipulate list views in VS Code using the keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77160922/11107541).

Once you have focused on the source control view, just press <kbd>up</kbd> or <kbd>down</kbd> until you reach it.

If the listing is not focused yet, and something else like the commit message input or commit button is focused instead, just press <kbd>tab</kbd> or <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> until it is. Ex. if the commit message input is focused, you should be able to just press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>.

Comment: This works for me, it is a little fiddly as after getting focus on the source control pane, you typically start with the commit message field selected. To get to the files then requires Tab, Tab, followed by a few down arrows. Not too bad once you have got used to it I guess.