# How can I cycle through all source control changes in a VS Code workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code, in a single file editor tab, there are commands to iterate thru changes in a file: `Next Change` and `Previous Change`. But how can I cycle through all changes across all the files in a workspace instead of a single file? Or maybe even better, how can I cycle through all the changed files in a workspace?

I searched such commands in the "keyboard shortcut" panel to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

Just an FYI: VS Code 1.85 shipped [a multi-file diff editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_85#_multifile-diff-editor). Quoting the release notes:

> The multi diff editor lets you view changes in multiple files in one scrollable view [[example video](https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/updates/1_85/multiFileDiffEditor.mp4)] To enable the multi diff editor, set `"multiDiffEditor.experimental.enabled": true`. Currently, the multi diff editor can be used to review local changes, staged changes, incoming/outgoing changes, and changes from pull requests. Note that the multi diff editor is not yet feature complete and might not work in all scenarios.

As stated above, the feature is currently experimental and you need to opt in with a settings change. The button to open the view is an action button in the row of action buttons in the "Changes" section for a repository in the Source Control View.

The related issue ticket is [Multi File Diff Editor #179000](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/179000).

---

You could open the Source Control View and just click through the list of Changes. If you want to use the keyboard, you can focus the View (primary sidebar) using <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>, and navigate the list items using the up and down arrow keys, and open a diff for the focused list item by pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>.

---

From googling "`github vscode issues keyboard shortcut next scm file`", I think you'll be interested in the following feature-request issue tickets:

- [SCM: Support workspace diff navigation #24389](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/24389)
- [Feature request: Keyboard shortcut for going to next changed file in the Git panel #145009](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/145009)

Give those issue tickets thumbs up reactions to show support for them, and subscribe to them to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments like "+1" / "bump" / "me too".

Someone [listed a workaround there](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/24389#issuecomment-1671151829) using the [geddski macros](https://github.com/geddski/macros) extension, which you may be interested to see. The workaround only supports cycling through files and not changes in those files, and doesn't automatically close the files when cycling through them. It also requires that you have selected an item in the SCM View's change listing recently so that the list has a sort of focus. Actually, that macros extension shouldn't be needed with [`runCommands`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_running-multiple-commands). You should be able to achieve the same thing like this:

```json
{
    "key": "", // TODO
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
        "commands": ["workbench.view.scm", "list.focusDown", "list.select"]
    }
},
{
    "key": "", // TODO
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
        "commands": ["workbench.view.scm", "list.focusUp", "list.select"]
    }
},
```

---

Someone also claims to have created an extension which does this: [`alfredbirk.go-to-next-change`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alfredbirk.go-to-next-change), which you could give a try. <sup><sub>(I have no affiliation with this extension)</sub></sup>

---

Note that if you're using the GitHub Pull Requests extension, that extension has a command called `Go to Next Diff in Pull Request` ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-pull-request-github/issues/1342#issuecomment-1346651522)).

Comment: thx starball. I should have  better explained my motivation. At that point I am not interested in diffs but just in a quick way to go thru my ongoing editions. Currently I walk my cursor history using the `Go back` command bound to `^ -`.  The 
[footsteps](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Wattenberger.footsteps) extension by Emilia Wattenberg has disturbing highlightings
I would expect something that work outside the context of the git or pull request extension and without the clutter of additional panels.

Answer (score 3):

VSCode currently does not support this natively.

However, I have created a [VSCode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alfredbirk.go-to-next-change) for this. It cycles through diffs in changed files with a shortcut. When at the end of a file, it will automatically jump to the next file.